# Binding does not work for Platform dependent Behaviors

Tags: xamarin, maui, community-toolkit-mvvm

Binding to observable property does not work when I try to create my own custom behavior. Neither it does in any of community mvvm toolkit platform behaviors:

https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/tree/main/src/CommunityToolkit.Maui/Behaviors/PlatformBehaviors

Take for example `StatusBarBehavior`, write something like

```
    <ContentPage.Behaviors>
        <toolkit:StatusBarBehavior StatusBarColor="{Binding StatusBarColorProp}" StatusBarStyle="LightContent" />
    </ContentPage.Behaviors>
```

create the property in your view model

```
    [ObservableProperty]
    private Color _statusBarColorProp;
```

you'll see status bar color does not change with `StatusBarBehavior` property change in runtime. Same for all the rest behaviors. It works fine for non-bindings setters like `StatusBarColor="Red"`.

I wonder if it's a feature or a bug, or I'm missing something.

**UPDATE** the issue is reported https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11729

Comment: *When* do you set `StatusBarColorProp`? I mean, what triggers the code that makes the change? Is it called from constructor? Some event?

Comment: button click event

Comment: You set the (generated) *property* `StatusBarColorProp`? Not the *field* `_statusBarColorProp`? `StatusBarColorProp = Color.Red;`?

Comment: sure, I set `StatusBarColorProp` in order to raise `OnPropertyChanged` event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can replicate your issue. And it turns out that we can only change the color of the `StatusBarColor` either in code behind like below or non-bindings setters like `StatusBarColor="Red"` as you mentioned.

```
 <ContentPage.Behaviors> 
        <toolkit:StatusBarBehavior x:Name="statusBar" ></toolkit:StatusBarBehavior>
 </ContentPage.Behaviors>
```

```
private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   statusBar.StatusBarColor = Colors.Red;
}
```

It fails to change the color of `StatusBarColor` when binding to an observable property. This could be a potential issue and I would suggest that you can raise a [Bug Report](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/new/choose) in Github.

Comment: thank you for making the verification check. I'm rather concerned about creating my own custom behaviors rather than making `StatusBarBehavior` work. So anyone could suggest me on what's missing in [StatusBarBehavior implementation](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/blob/main/src/CommunityToolkit.Maui/Behaviors/PlatformBehaviors/StatusBar/StatusBarBehavior.shared.cs) or [IconTintColorBehavior implementation](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/blob/main/src/CommunityToolkit.Maui/Behaviors/PlatformBehaviors/IconTintColor/IconTintColorBehavior.android.cs) in order to make it work

Comment: ... or just a link to Platform Behavior derived control that does a proper binding implementation would suffice, as long as issue is in the behavior implementation, not in the maui framework itself

Comment: Implementation looks correct. I suspect a bug in Maui; it isn't "propagating" that bound change. That is, the binding from StatusBarPropColor to BindableProperty StatusBarColor should "cascade" (the changed value) to any dependents of StatusBarColor, exactly like the working code `statusBar.StatusBarColor = Colors.Red;`. This problem likely existed in XForms also; I've encountered similar "gotchas" writing custom controls.

Answer (score 0):

Please file a bug issue at github maui issues.

In the meantime, try this gross hack in one of your properties:

```cs
static public BindableProperty MyValueProperty = BindableProperty.Create(...,
  propertyChanged: (bindable, oldValue, newValue) =>
  {
    var it = (MyClass)bindable;
    // If it is changing, force explicit OnPropertyChanged. This is usually redundant,
    // but might help a binding "cascade" to dependencies.
    if (!(MyType)newValue.Equals((MyType)oldvalue))
      it.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MyValue));
  });
public MyType MyValue
{
  get => (MyType)GetValue(MyValueProperty);
  set => SetValue(MyValueProperty, value);
}
```

Comment: filed new issue https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11729

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar binding problem. **Behavior class**:

```
public class EntryNumericBehavior : Behavior<Entry>
{
     public static readonly BindableProperty MinValueProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(MinValue), typeof(int), typeof(EntryNumericBehavior));

     public int MinValue
     {
        get => (int)GetValue(MinValueProperty);
        set { SetValue(MinValueProperty, value); }
     }
    
}
```

**Binding in XAML**. ***MinTemperature*** - source property:

```
<Entry>
    <Entry.Behaviors>
        <ViewModels:EntryNumericBehavior MinValue="{Binding MinTemperature}"/>
    </Entry.Behaviors>
</Entry>
```

During experiments, it turned out that if ***MinTemperature*** is bound to Label, you can bind to it in XAML (*crutch*):

```
<Label Text="{Binding MinTemperature}" x:Name="MinLabel"/>
<Entry>
    <Entry.Behaviors>
        <ViewModels:EntryNumericBehavior MinValue="{Binding Source={x:Reference MinLabel}, Path=Text}"/>
    </Entry.Behaviors>
</Entry>
```

I realize it's not a great solution, but it's a temporary one.